# How to deal with "deep" nested union types

Tags: typescript

In the logic below I am trying to type the data that is coming as balanceModel parameter to the function but straggle a bit with the deep nested model and will appreciate a lot if somebody can point out the flaw in the types below.

**Here is a live example of the logic below in codesandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-meitner-vxto9

```
type BalanceModelAMDRType = {
  from: number;
  to: number;
  [index: string]: number;
};
type BalanceModelSectionType = {
  DRI: {
    AI: number;
    AMDR: BalanceModelAMDRType;
    EAR: number;
    RDA: number;
    UL: number;
    unit: string;
    [index: string]: string | number | BalanceModelAMDRType;
  };
};

type BalanceModelProgressSectionType = {
  DRI: {
    recommended: number;
    unit: string;
    [index: string]: string | number;
  };
};

type BalanceModelType = {
  energy: BalanceModelSectionType;
  [index: string]: BalanceModelSectionType | BalanceModelProgressSectionType;
};

function _updateEnergyDependentSections(
  balanceModel: BalanceModelType,
  energy: number
): void {
  const sections = [`mock`, `data`];

  sections.forEach(sectionName => {
    if (balanceModel[sectionName]) {
      const { DRI } = balanceModel[sectionName];

      Object.keys(DRI).forEach(DRIName => {
        switch (true) {
          case sectionName === `mock`:
            const AMDR = DRI[DRIName];

            Object.keys(AMDR).forEach(AMDRValueName => {
              const AMDRValue = AMDR[AMDRValueName];
              AMDR[AMDRValueName] = Math.round(
                AMDRValue * conversionMultiplier
              );
            });
            break;

          case sectionName === `data`:
            DRI[DRIName] = Math.round(DRI[DRIName] * conversionMultiplier);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Your problem definition is a bit too broad. Can you be more specific about what you're looking to fix? After a precursory look over the errors, it looks like either you don't validate your union types enough (using [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)), or your model is wrong, and doesn't match the structure of the data. (for instance data sections seem to hold numbers, while mocked sections seem to hold objects. You can probably use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) for that)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion artcorpse, typeguards were indeed needed for this case and thank you very much for sharing link about generics :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly.

```
const AMDR = DRI[DRIName]
```

could be `string | number | BalanceModelAMDRType`.

In `mock` section you want it be `BalanceModelAMDRType` and in `data` as number.

if you know for a fact that it will always be in those type in that moment, you add `as 
type"` to end, like

```
const AMDR = DRI[DRIName] as BalanceModelAMDRType; or
const AMDR = DRI[DRIName] as number;
```

if you do not know for a fact that in those instances the value will be in those types, you need to use a type guard(if statement).

```
if(typeof AMDR !== 'number' or typeof AMDR !== 'string'){ // AMDR is BalanceModelAMDRType }
if(typeof AMDR == 'number'){ //AMDR is number }
```

You can add a property to a `type`(interface), which will identify it as well, like:

```
type BalanceModelAMDRType = {
  type: "AMDR";
  from: number;
   to: number;
  } & { [index: string]: number };
```

and have a type guard function:

```
function isBalanceModelAMDRType(v: any): v is BalanceModelAMDRType {
  return "type" in v && v.type === "AMDR";
}
```

Comment: You are actually right using type guards was actually needed for this case :-) Thank you very much for the help